# Adding data rows based on string list in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am new to flutter and trying to update the rows in "DataTable" based on the options selected in dropdown. For instance, consider the below example.
[image: imag1]

If I have selected Maid 1 and Maid 2, then the table should look like
[image: image2]

I am storing this maid 1 and maid 2 in a String List named SelectValue1. So, is there any possibility of showing in the above format at the rows section of DataTable? If there is, it would be great help. Dropping the code for further reference.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:custom_searchable_dropdown/custom_searchable_dropdown.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
//import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

//CUSTOMER LOGIN PAGE

class CustomerHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomerHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Customer Home Page"),
        titleSpacing: 00.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        toolbarHeight: 60.2,
        toolbarOpacity: 0.8,
        /*shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
          ),*/
        elevation: 0.00,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Container(child: Container(child: C_HP())),
    );
  }
}

// stateful widget created for calendar class
class C_HP extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CHPState createState() => _CHPState();
}

class _CHPState extends State<C_HP> {
  List<String> items = ["Maid 1", "Maid 2", "Maid 3", "Maid 4"];
  String dropdownSelected = '';
  List<String> selectedValue1 = [];
  String jsonstring_names = "";
  // bool _value = false;
  bool _valu1 = false;
  bool _valu2 = false;
  bool _valu3 = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      Row(children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 80,
            width: 450,
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              title: const Text('Cleaning'),
              subtitle:
                  const Text('select the checkbox to have cleaning services'),
              secondary: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/other_background_image.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0), // Optionally
                side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              autofocus: false,
              isThreeLine: true,
              activeColor: Colors.blue,
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              selected: _valu1,
              value: _valu1,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                  _valu1 = value ?? true;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Flexible(
            child: SizedBox(
          height: 80,
          width: 500,
          child: CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text('Cooking'),
            subtitle:
                const Text('select the checkbox to have cooking services'),
            secondary: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/other_background_image.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0), // Optionally
              side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            autofocus: false,
            isThreeLine: true,
            activeColor: Colors.blue,
            checkColor: Colors.white,
            selected: _valu2,
            value: _valu2,
            onChanged: (bool? value2) {
              setState(() {
                _valu2 = value2 ?? true;
              });
            },
          ),
        )),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 80,
            width: 500,
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              title: const Text('Elderly Care'),
              subtitle: const Text(
                  'select the checkbox to have Elderly Care services'),
              secondary: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/other_background_image.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0), // Optionally
                side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              autofocus: false,
              isThreeLine: true,
              activeColor: Colors.blue,
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              selected: _valu3,
              value: _valu3,
              onChanged: (bool? value3) {
                setState(() {
                  _valu3 = value3 ?? true;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      SizedBox(
        height: 40,
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            child: DropdownSearch<String>.multiSelection(
              items: items,
              popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.menu(
                showSelectedItems: true,
                disabledItemFn: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
              ),

              onChanged: (List<String> selectedValue) {
                /*dropdownSelected =
                      selectedValue.isNotEmpty ? selectedValue[0] : '';*/
                // print(selectedValue);
                selectedValue1 = [...selectedValue]; //LIST IS BEING STORED Here
                print("SelectedValue1");
                print(selectedValue1);

                print("jsonstring_names");
                print(jsonstring_names);
              },
              //selectedItems: items,
            )),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 40,
      ),
      SizedBox(
          height: 500,
          width: 850,
          child: DataTable(columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('ID'),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Name'),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Occupied Days'),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Occupied Dates'),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Age'),
            ),
          ], rows: [
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text("1")),
              DataCell(Text("Alexa")),
              DataCell(Text("Sunday")),
              DataCell(Text("01/01/2024")),
              DataCell(Text("18")),
            ]),
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text("2")),
              DataCell(Text("Alex")),
              DataCell(Text("Sunday")),
              DataCell(Text("01/01/2024")),
              DataCell(Text("18")),
            ]),
          ]))
    ]

        // create calendar

        );
  }
}
```

thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own dynamic table row in a separate widget, then by using a list view builder, you can iterate through the `SelectedValue` array and return that widget with values you specify, Here's an example of how you can implement a ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: stringArray.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text(
            stringArray[index],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Replace the child in this code with your widget and customize it accordingly.

Comment: This can be very helpful . But, I am able to use this in a DataCell() by which I am able to see Maid 1 and Maid 2 in 1 row rather than displaying them in 2 different rows.